# Why does the Ford-Fulkerson Maximum flow algorithm not work for irrational capacities?

Tags: graphs, network-flow, ford-fulkerson

Can anyone help me understand why the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm does not work in the case of irrational capacities?

Comment: Take a look in the wikipedia page for the algorithm, there is a non-terminating example there

Comment: Thanks, I will check